# Enforcing developers to use a Builder to build an instance

Tags: java, design-patterns, orm, builder

I have a few `POJOs` that have certain rules to adhere. The state of **ObjectA** of type **A** depends upon the state of **ObjectB** of type **B**. In this situation I use a builder to enforce the rules of **ObjectB** on **ObjectA**.

The builder takes responsibility to do all validations, throws exceptions and performs checks when **ObjectA** is being built. This is not the problem. I want developers in the future to instantiate and manipulate type **A**, using the builder. How can I enforce this?

Here are some of my options, which would be the best direction to take:

1. Document, not so effective if a developer doesn't read the document, besides if something can be done, some one will do.
2. Move the validations into the `POJO`, but I use an *ORM* and seldom it throws errors when properties are being set.
3. Your thoughts on this problem.

Comment: Place the `Builder` and `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` in the same package. Then make the constructor for `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` protected. That way the builder is the only one that can create them.

Comment: +1 for your suggestion, I tried and it worked!

Comment: @ahenderson Please post your solution as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `Builder`,`ObjectA`, and `ObjectB` in the same package. Then make the constructor for `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` protected. That way the builder is the only one that can create them.

Answer (score 2):

Use a static inner builder.

Or make constructor protected and put builder in same package with public interface

Comment: Thanks, it worked! @ahenderson, gave me the same solution as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that given these are POJOs, making the constructor less than public is not an option, as this would cause the trouble with the ORM?

If making the constructor non-public *is* a possibility, you could make the builder a static subclass of the POJO class, and make the constructor private, preventing others from instantiating the POJO directly.

But you should be able to at least use the `@Deprecated` annotation to provide a warning for using the POJO's constructor. And you can then use `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` on the Builder method that does the instantiation to get a clean build.

Comment: I thought of this as well, but this solution has the same problem as 1. Also a @SuppressWarning("Deprecated") would hide the compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Just ensure that the constructor of your class A can't be called directly. Make it `private` and create the builder as a static inner class which can access the constructor. Then (optionally) create in A a method

```
public static Builder builder() {
    return new Builder();
}
```

to access the builder in a convenient way. You can also pass external dependencies (like B) to this method.

Comment: I agree with the method of inner static class. I think you could have put a more useful code segment than that static helper function however. What does it do apart from hide the `new`? Which could actually be misleading with that name as it doesn't suggest it creates a new builder.

Comment: You are completely right. newBuilder is a better name. I think such a method is really useful because now you can call MyObject.builder() instead of new MyObject.Builder(), which feels quite cumbersome.